# How to move div to top and remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two block inside container and under them button. I need, when I click on the button, then the first div slowly moves up and removed. I tried so:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<button class="move">Click</button>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block
}

.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 5px;
}

.move {
    display: block
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.move').click(function() {
        $('.block:first-child').animate({scrollTop: '-100px'}, 1000, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

But when I click on the button, then first `.block` just removed. I need to first move it up. How to fix it?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lor8vL00/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're animating the `scrollTop` of the element which will not have the effect you want. You can animate the `height` instead. However there is also the `slideUp()` function which will do this for you. Try this:

```
$('.move').click(function() {
    $('.block:first-child').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xkutb9w/)

If you have to do it without resizing the block, you can set `overflow: hidden` on the container, then animate the `margin-top` of the block itself.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lor8vL00/2/)

Comment: Ha! At some point I thought he has asking for literally moving the element up.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, Excellent, exactly what is needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Pearson no problem, glad to help. Note that `slideUp` also takes a duration if you want to use it; `slideUp(1000, function() {});`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, although no, by clicking the first block changes the size, I need that it is entirely moved up. I have background in the block and this effect looks not good. http://jsfiddle.net/Lor8vL00/1/

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: relative` to element. `top` property works on positioned elements that is position is anything other than `static`. `position: relative` suits in this case.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.move').click(function() {
        $('.block:first-child').animate({
          top: '-100px'
        }, 1000, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      });
    });
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block
}
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative
}
.move {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<button class="move">Click</button>
```

Comment: Good, but I need without white space between blocks!